# Can the LOG file fill up from index rebuilds where the indexes are not fragmented?

Tags: sql-server, index, transaction-log

Working on SQL Server 2014.

I have noticed that a log file (60GB) on a database has filled up within the past day. To my knowledge, I am the only developer using this database and I have not been performing any transactions on the database for over a week. I asked the DBA if anyone else is using the database and they did not think so. The DBA mentioned that the automated index rebuild jobs could be filling up the log.

My question is this, can automated index rebuild jobs that run hourly fill up the log file? My assumption here is that the index would not be fragmented and so there would not be any work to rebuild the index. Therefor, the log file should not fill up. Is this assumption false? Am I missing something with how SQL Server index rebuilds work and how that might impact the log file?

**Update**

We are using Ola's solution: [Click Here](https://ola.hallengren.com/)

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = N'\\DirectoryPath\',
@MirrorDirectory = N'\\DirectoryPath\',
@BackupType = 'LOG',
@Verify = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 48,
@MirrorCleanupTime=24,
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@LogToTable = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y'
```

Comment: *My question is this, can automated index rebuild jobs that run hourly fill up the log file?* --> Yes. Did index rebuilds happen in the database or not? If you are using [Ola](https://ola.hallengren.com/)'s solution then check the `dbo.commandlog` table if `@LogtoTable = 'Y'` (Or add it to the command). Is the database in the full recovery model and are you taking log backups? And running hourly index rebuilds seems a bit much to me, I would really look into scheduling this less often or even [not doing it](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/11/good-reasons-rebuild-reorganize-indexes/)

Comment: @RandiVertongen Yes, we are using Ola's solution. Yes, we take log backups hourly. Note: the log backup job is failing due to an infrastructure issue. This has allowed me to catch the fact that the log file is filling up - unexpectedly I would say.

Comment: Alright, if you have the  `@logtotable` param set you should see the indexes that where rebuild / reorganized in that timeframe when querying the  `dbo.commandlog` table

Comment: @RandiVertongen I found the `dbo.CommandLog` in the a database called `DBAUtils` (I previously was looking in `Master`). So, the Index rebuild job is disabled. The only transactions I see are for are log backups - the DBA's postulation was incorrect. This seems like a wasted question since the index rebuilds should not be causing the log file to fill up.

Comment: Alright thanks for letting me know! Good that you have it sorted then :)

Comment: @RandiVertongen It doesn't answer the question as to why the LOG file filled up. I understand that the DBA trace is about the only thing I can rely on. Can you think of anything else to troubleshoot? I can modify the question if needed.

Comment: The log is filling up because the log backup job is failing.

Comment: @TonyHinkle The log backup job last ran successfully two days ago. It is now failing due to infrastructure reason. If I have not performed any transactions, and index rebuilds aren't running, what is filling the log?

Comment: A more advanced approach is reading the contents of the log file. with the undocumented `fn_dblog` function. `USE DbWithBigLog SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)` and trying to see what kind of operations are in there. If nothing is happening the log should not be full. It is hard to say what exactly without more information.

Comment: @RandiVertongen I was unaware of this, thank you. In running it, the output looks like machine language, so I do not know how to read it. This is an expert concept I will need to learn. As luck would have it, the infrastructure issue has been resolved and the log file has been mostly cleared by the log backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this, can automated index rebuild jobs that run hourly fill up the log file?

Yes. An index rebuild typically rewrites all of the data contained in the index. I don't know of any exceptions, but there might be some. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-2017):

> Rebuilding an index drops and re-creates the index. This removes
>   fragmentation, reclaims disk space by compacting the pages based on
>   the specified or existing fill factor setting, and reorders the index
>   rows in contiguous pages.

You also asked:

> My assumption here is that the index would not be fragmented and so there would not be any work to rebuild the index. Therefor, the log file should not fill up. Is this assumption false?

Fragmentation does not matter because a new copy of the data is created. You may be thinking of the `REORGANIZE` command. The amount of work performed by that command depends on fragmentation of the data, but it's done in small transactions.